# What does highlighted dependencies mean in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have some highlighted dependencies in android studio and I don't know where it's came from and how to remove it?

[image: Here is the screen of the problem]

I have been looking all over stack-overflow and google but I can't see any reference of this.

Comment: Hint: Place your mouse pointer over the highlighted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it suggests you to update the version of the dependency. 
Mouseover that highlights to see what it wants.

On OS X I usually press alt+enter and accept the suggested correction.

[image: result of mouseover on highlight]